# How can i count the reactions in discord.js and after that display it (slappey version)

Tags: javascript, count, discord

I'm trying to display who win the poll but i run into a problem. While I want to get the number of the reactions with

```
.addField(":", `${results.get("").count}`)
```

My console says that the count is undefined. I've tried to search it but I didn't find anything and I tried so many ways but nothing.

The code:

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require("discord.js")
module.exports = class HelpCommand extends BaseCommand {
    constructor() {
        super('vote', 'moderation', []);
    }
    async run(client, message, args) {
        const filter = m => m.author.id == message.author.id; 

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}  started the poll`)
            .setTimestamp();

        message.channel.send('what the question is?');

        try {
            let msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] });
            console.log(msg.first().content);
            embed.setTitle(msg.first().content);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            message.channel.send('You run out of time! Pls type again the command \`~prefix~ vote\`');
        }


        message.channel.send('first option?');

        try {
            let msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] });
            console.log(msg.first().content);
            embed.addField(`[] the first option:`, msg.first().content);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            message.channel.send('You run out of time! Pls type again the command \`~prefix~ vote\`');
        }

        message.channel.send('second option?');

        try {
            let msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] });
            console.log(msg.first().content);
            embed.addField(`[] the second option`, msg.first().content);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            message.channel.send('You run out of time! Pls type again the command \`~prefix~ vote\`');
        }

        try {
            await message.channel.bulkDelete(7)
                .then(message.channel.send(embed).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.react('')).then(reaction => reaction.message.react('')));


        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        const filters = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name === "" || reaction.emoji.name === "";

        const results = await message.awaitReactions(filters, { time: 15000 })


        let resultsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`the poll result`)
            .setDescription(`the result of the poll: ${args.join(" ")}`)
            .addField(":", `${results.get("").count}`)
            .addField(":", `${results.get("").count //if i dont type here the .count then i've got this embed but after the "": says'undefined' }`)
            .setColor("#84daf8")
            .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(resultsEmbed);
      }
    }
```

[A szavazás eredménye = The poll result in my language. I see this when i dont write the .count there: `` .addField(":", `${results.get("").count}`) ``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKK6N.png)

[and i see this when i write .count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UXF5.png)

Comment: Try `console.log(results);` first and see what the console says.

Comment: ```Collection(0) [Map] {} ```

nothing more after while i'm react

Comment: Then your `awaitReactions` method isn't registering your reactions properly. Check to see if the message you are reacting to is the one that the `awaitReactions` is awaiting for. By that, I mean just check nearby messages and react to them in different reaction combinations, one red, one blue, one red and blue, etc. and see what the `console.log(results);` shows at the end.

Comment: i've got tha same message ```Collection(0) [Map] {} ``` I'm react some normal messages and all of my poll with different combination. https://imgur.com/a/bbE1yUV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the bot was trying to retrieve the reactions of a deleted message I believe. In order to fix this, you'll have to put your `resultsEmbed` code inside of your chained `then` methods.

Code:

```js
try {
    await message.channel.bulkDelete(7)
        .then(message.channel.send(embed)
            .then(sentMessage => sentMessage.react(''))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react(''))
            .then(reaction => {
                const filters = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name === "" || reaction.emoji.name === "";

                reaction.message.awaitReactions(filters, { time: 15000 }).then(collected => {
                    console.log(collected);

                    if (collected.get("") !== undefined && collected.get("") !== undefined) {
                        let optionOne = collected.get("").count;
                        let optionTwo = collected.get("").count;
                        let resultsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle("the poll result")
                            .setDescription(`the result of the poll: ${args.join(" ")}`)
                            .addField(":", `${optionOne}`)
                            .addField(":", `${optionTwo}`)
                            .setColor('#')
                            .setTimestamp()
                        message.channel.send(resultsEmbed);
                    } else {
                        //there were no votes for one of the options, thus it will not be able to get property
                        message.channel.send("There were no votes for one of the options.");
                    }
                })
            })
        );
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```